# IB plug in for CALayer subclass

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, plugins

I am developing a game with dozens of levels and each level has a unique layer tree with objects that are a subclass of CALayer. I would like to use Interface Builder to set up and layout each level, is it possible to create an IB plug-in for my CALayer subclass which would let me do this? The documentation refers only to subclasses of views and control; I'd rather not invest the effort of learning about plugins if its not possible.

Thanks, Martin

Comment: FYI, I implemented a solution using IB after all. I use UIViews with custom classes, layout each level in a different NIB using the custom classes then at run time, I load the NIB for the required level and extract position and other information (e.g. hierarchy) from the views, then create CALayers to match the views in the NIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to create Interface Builder plugins for your own iPhone user interface elements. (Confirmed by Apple on the Dev Forum)